# Label Size is always NaN?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have a Panel which I want to extend and override MeassureOverride and Arrange to have my custom layout. 
Basically, the panel will contain some labels. As the label has some text content, it should have a specific size. However when I use label.ActualHeight or actualwidth, desiredSize ... in the MeassureOverride or ArrangeOverride, all result to NaN. Is there any way I can get the desired Size of the label so that the text content is fit?

Comment: Could you post what you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you call base.MeasureOverride(abailableSize) and base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize) at the end of each method?

[Here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/lee_roth/archive/2009/08/21/custom-panels-in-silverlight-wpf-part-1-measureoverride.aspx) is an example of creating a custom panel

A custom implementation of MeasureOverride might look like this (from the post):

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
    Size sizeSoFar = new Size(0, 0);
    double maxWidth = 0.0;

    foreach (UIElement child in Children)
    {
        child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));

        if (sizeSoFar.Width + child.DesiredSize.Width > availableSize.Width)
        {
            sizeSoFar.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            sizeSoFar.Width = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sizeSoFar.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            maxWidth = Math.Max(sizeSoFar.Width, maxWidth);
        }
    }

    return new Size(maxWidth, sizeSoFar.Height);
}
```

A custom implementation of ArrangeOverride might look like this (from the post):

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    Size sizeSoFar = new Size(0, 0);

    foreach (UIElement child in Children)
    {
        child.Arrange(new Rect(sizeSoFar.Width, sizeSoFar.Height, 
                               child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));

        if (sizeSoFar.Width + child.DesiredSize.Width >= finalSize.Width)
        {
            sizeSoFar.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
            sizeSoFar.Width = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            sizeSoFar.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }
    }

    return finalSize;
}
```

If you want to force the panel rendering (call the MeasureOverride function), use the [InvalidateMeasure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatemeasure(VS.95).aspx) function

You could also check out [Custom Panel Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels%5Fcustom%5Fpanel%5Felements) on msdn.

Comment: Hi DevMan, thanks for your answer. I didn't use the base methods. I My DesiredSize is NaN is it because the Panel is contained inside a Grid, which I set its Size to Auto ?? (however, i have set the MinHeight, MinWidth Property as well)

Answer (score 2):

The `DesiredSize` for each child is only set after you have measured it. In your `MeasureOverride` you must call `child.Measure()` for every of your panel's children. The same goes with `child.Arrange()` in `ArrangeOverride`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx#LayoutSystem_Measure_Arrange

**Edit in response to your comment:** just pass the maximum size your label could have (the available size), or a constrained size if you need to. The label once measured will use its minimum size as the `DesiredSize` if the alignments are different from stretch.

Comment: Hi Julien. Thanks for your help. As I understand, the MeasureOverride method is for the child Elements to tell it parent how much space it needs. 
But if I can't get its DesiredSize before Measure, how can I tell how much width n height the Panel need to accommodate its text content? 
In other words, what's should I return in each measure call if not the DesiredSize of the Label?